# Check solution to the SDE $dX_t = - \mu X_t \, dt+ \sigma \, dW_t$

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

I get stuck in this problem. I just can't get the hang of how we need to "guess" a function first and almost everything along the process of solving depends on it; It's not entirely logical to me when it comes to guessing it.

> Let $dX_t=-\mu X_t \, dt+ \sigma \, dW_t$ for all $t$ where $W_t$ denotes a standard Brownian motion and $\mu,\sigma, X_0$ are positive constants. Prove that
>
> $$X_t=e^{-\mu t}X_0+\sigma \int_0^t e^{-\mu (t-u)} \, dW_u$$
>
> for every $t$.

My attempt

> Let $f(t,x)=\ln x$ then $Y_t:=\ln W_t$. Using Ito's equation, we have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=0$,$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{x}$ and $\frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x^2}=-\frac{1}{x^2}$.
>
> But using this simply doesn't get me exactly where I want. Something slightly close though. My choice of $f$ is due to seeing $e$ in the final expression I want.

At times like this I am very stuck and wonder if I am not getting what I want because of my choice of $f$ or because I still haven't manipulated my expression enough(given my choice of $f$ was correct), or if I have made some minor miscalculation. I just don't know which one.

Can someone tell me how to prove this at all please??

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you already know how the solution looks like, there is no need to guess functions first. Just use Itô's formula to check that the given process is indeed a solution to the SDE.

Obviously, we have

$$X_t = e^{-\mu t} Y_t \tag{1}$$

for

$$Y_t := X_0 + \sigma \int_0^t e^{u \mu} \, dW_u. \tag{2}$$

Note that $(Y_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is an Itô process. Applying Itô's formula (for Itô processes) with

$$f(t,y) := e^{-\mu t} y$$

we get

$$\begin{align*} X_t- X_0 &= f(t,Y_t)-f(0,Y_0) \\ &= \int_0^t \partial_y f(s,Y_s) \, dY_s + \int_0^t \partial_t f(s,Y_s) \, ds + \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t \partial_{y}^2 f(s,Y_s) \, d\langle Y \rangle_s \\ &\stackrel{\star}{=} \underbrace{\int_0^t e^{-\mu s} \, dY_s}_{\stackrel{(1)}{=} \sigma \int_0^t \, dW_s} - \mu \int_0^t \underbrace{e^{-\mu s} Y_s}_{\stackrel{(2)}{=} X_s} \, ds \\ &= \sigma \int_0^t  \, dW_s -\mu \int_0^t X_s \, ds \end{align*}$$

where we have used in $(\star)$ that

$$\partial_y f(t,y) = e^{-\mu t} \quad \partial_y^2 f(t,y) = 0 \quad \partial_t f(t,y) = - \mu e^{-\mu t} y.$$

Comment: Hi thanks for answering; My question is, you seem to have used as if it is already a fact, that $X_t$ is of the form that is given. I was wondering, as under the context "prove", I thought we cannot assume that $X_t$ is in that form? And also I'm not sure about how the last bit would become the final answer....$\int_0^t dW_s=W_t$, no? Then, wouldn't your answer conclude that $X_t=X_0+\sigma W_T-\mu \int_0^t X_sds$? Is this the same form as $X_t$ we given to prove?

Comment: @JohnTrail I *defined* $X_t$ in this way and showed that it solves the given SDE. Since the SDE has a unique solution, this means that the process $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is the unique solution of the SDE. Note that $$X_t = X_0 + \sigma W_t - \mu \int_0^t X_s \, ds$$ is equivalent to $$dX_t = \sigma \, dW_t - \mu X_t \, dt.$$

Comment: I see, so i's basically "checking the solution". I promise this is the last question as I understand everything else here now; Why is $\int e^{-\mu　s }dY_s$ equal to $\sigma \int dW_s$? you mentioned equation $(1)$ in the transition so I tried fiddling with the integral and the equation $(1)$ but I didn't really reach $\sigma \int dW_s$ I might be missing something very simple, if I can get this cleared, I'll have your answer accepted, thank you!!

Comment: @JohnTrail Yes, it's basically checking the solution, since -lucky you- you are given the solution :). Concerning your question: $(1)$ gives $$dY_u = \sigma e^{u \mu} \, dW_u,$$ or, if we just rename the variable, $$dY_s = \sigma e^{s \mu} \, dW_s.\tag{3} $$ Therefore, $$\int_0^t e^{-\mu s} \, dY_s \stackrel{(3)}{=} \int_0^t e^{-\mu s} \left( \sigma e^{s \mu} \, dW_s \right) = \sigma \int_0^t \, dW_s.$$

Comment: Thanks! That was clear(though, I think...the equation you've used is actually $(2)$ above $Y_t= X_0+\sigma \int e^{-(u \mu}dW_s$ which matches your calculation. But still it solved my mystery, highly appreciate your taking some time to help me in my studies, thank you once again!

Comment: @JohnTrail Yeah, sorry, I meant $(2)$. You are welcome.